# Claiming compensation for Ryanair after diversion

Tags: compensation, ryanair

Last month I had a horrible flight experience with Ryanair. We left Madrid with a three hour delay and when we were about to land in Stansted we were diverted to Birmingham because the runway was closed for scheduled maintenance (Ryanair must have known this before we left Madrid). We were not given a reason for the initial delay.

As a result of this I arrived to Stansted at 4:40 am, instead of 23:40pm as scheduled. According to EU261 I should be entitled to compensation.

I submitted a complaint through Ryanair's service but it was rejected. In the rejection email it said
"If you are unhappy with our decision, you can take your complaint to your local Alternative Dispute Resolution (ADR) body, details of which can be found in our help centre page on our website."

However I am not sure if this will get me anywhere. Does anyone have any recommendation for what to do next?

Thanks

Comment: You may not be sure if it will get you anywhere, but you'll _never_ know if you don't take the complaint to the ADR. Why don't you just start with that?

Comment: What was the date of travel?

Comment: @jcaron the date of travel was November 20th 2022.

Comment: @FreeMan can you share a link with the appropriate ADR to use? the one I found says they don't take complaints for incidents after 2019. Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect that "details of which can be found in our help centre page on our website." I haven't a clue. If their provided link doesn't accept incidents after 2019, then you would probably need to ask Ryanair for a more current link.